# Get full path of .sln file

Tags: tfs, msbuild

How does one get the full physical path of the .sln file when scripting in MSBuild?

I'm trying to force nuget to download packages using:

```
<Target Name="BeforeCompileConfiguration">
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(ToolsHome)NuGet\NuGet.exe&quot; restore &quot;$(SolutionRoot)\KK\MyProject.sln&quot;" />
</Target>
```

KK is the name of the folder that the .sln file is under. I'd like to replace

```
$(SolutionRoot)\KK\MyProject.sln
```

with a single $() build property.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(SolutionPath)
```

should do your job!

By the way it's equivalent to:

```
   $(SolutionDir)$(SolutionFileName)
```